# Execute PHP code inside HTML select

Tags: php, html, forms, select

I'd like to do something like this :

```
 <select name="cities">
 <option value="<?php=$row['city']?>"><?php=$row['city']?></option>
 </select>
```

But the previous code doesn't work.

Does somebody know how to fix this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<option value="<?php echo $row['city']; ?>">
  <?php echo $row['city']; ?>
</option>
```

You have to `echo` it out ;)

Answer (score 5):

I think you mean either `<?= $variable ?>` or `<?php echo $variable; ?>`. You can't combine the two.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's the `<?php=`.

Either try `<?php echo $row['city'] ?>` or `<?= $row['city'] ?>`.

The second version is the shorthand which is not always enabled and therefore there's no guarantee that it's going to work.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible:

```
<?php=$row['city']?>
```

I guess you mean:

```
<?php echo $row['city']; ?>
```

See: [Escaping from HTML<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php)

If you want to use this:

```
<?= $row['city'] ?>
```

Get PHP 5.4 or enable [`short_open_tag`<sup>*Ini*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) in your php.ini.

Answer (score 1):

there is no such thing as `<?php= [...] ?>`
use `<?php echo [...] ?>` or `<?= [...] ?>` instead. I personally prefer the first.